# Windows phone ads not working

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to integrate ads into a already successful deployed app. However no matter what I do, I cannot seem to get the ads working. I have tried using both the code version and the drag n' drop gui version. Neither of which I can get to work.

This is what I see: When it starts up it may flash for a split second white, where the ad is supposed to be, but none the less, no adds. It recognizes that it is where I place it, when I place it over a button, the button becomes unclickable. All being said, no default "microsoft advertising" image pops up. I have installed the ad SDK and have successfully been able to make the ads display in other project with ease.

What gives? This is very simple page and I cannot figure out what is wrong. It also seems that I cannot place an ad on any of the other pages either... I do have the Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile and Microsoft.Advertising. Mobile.UI included in the project and my internet is working (I have an project open at the same time with ads and it works)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="AppName.AdPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Margin="12,17,12,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Thank You!" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" Width="334" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0" Height="569" VerticalAlignment="Top">

            <Button Content="Ok" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,428,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
            <my:AdControl AdUnitId="Image480_80" ApplicationId="test_client" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,458,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;
using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile;
namespace Stickey_Note_v._1
{
    public partial class AdPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public AdPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue and wrote a [blog post](http://whiletruecode.tumblr.com/tagged/Windows-Phone) about it. Here's the important stuff:

The symptoms of a problem with the SDK's `AdControl` seem to be pretty consistent: The page loads, the control flickers briefly, showing the hint of a 1 pixel frame, and then, *poof*. It collapses into nothingness, leaving only a black hole of dispair.

In theory, setting up the `AdControl` is simple. The [documentation from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-7-visual-studio-designer%28v=MSADS.20%29.aspx) outlines the basics:

- Download and install the [Microsoft Advertising SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8729).
- Add a reference to `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI`.
- Drag the control onto the page in the Visual Studio designer.
- Set the `AdUnitId` and `ApplicationId` properties to either test values or actual live values, which you can obtain from Microsoft pubCenter.

But it couldn't be that easy. I followed the documentation carefully, but nothing was working. I couldn't even get test ads to show up, which seemed really weird. I even reverted to an older version of my app (yay source control!) and dropped in the new .dll. Failure.

Finally, I found a clue in an [obscure forum post](http://community.microsoftadvertising.com/forums/p/69880/102113.aspx#102113).

The Microsoft documentation neglects to mention several important details. You need to pay particular attention to the following if you're upgrading an existing project to the Mango ad SDK, as I was:

- You must specify a height and width for the `AdControl`. Failing to specify the `Height` and `Width` attributes, or setting them to `auto`, will cause tears of frustration. I'd recommend 80 pixels high and 480 pixels wide, as that's the native size of the ads that Microsoft serves up.
- It seems that you can't have two `AdControls` on the same page, or at least not in the same parent element. The second one will collapse. There might be a way around this, but I discovered it while building my demo app and didn't care to pursue a solution.
- You must must must specify certain capabilities in your `WMAppManifest.xml` file. Since I was upgrading my app, I didn't have some of the newer capabilities declared. The one that was causing all the trouble was `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER`. The following capabilities are all required for the control to function correctly:

> ```
> <Capabilities>
>     <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
>     <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
>     <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
>     <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"/>
>     <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
> </Capabilities>
> ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You sir, are more than just exceptionally helpful :) It turned out that I did not include <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/> lol go figure

Comment: Hah, nice. :) Glad to be of service.

Comment: Somehow the required capabillities vanished from your answer. You need the following:
    ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER,
    ID_CAP_NETWORKING,
    ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT,
    ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER,
    ID_CAP_MEDIALIB.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288088.aspx

Comment: FWIW I had the same problem with my test ads not showing up (Windows Phone 8) and updating the WMAppManifest.xml file is what fixed the problem! Many thanks!

Comment: I think you also need to do Location to make it show up. This worked though.

Comment: For my WP8 project, there was no ID_CAP_MEDIALIB capability.  I was able to get it working by adding ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem could come from (if you didn't remove it for posting it here):

```
 <my:AdControl AdUnitId="Image480_80" ApplicationId="test_client" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,458,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" />
        </Grid>
```

You have to use AdUnitId and ApplicationId which you get from [pubCenter](https://pubcenter.microsoft.com/Login).

Comment: Yes, I have gotten the credentials but for testing, the credentials there will (should) display a default image in place of an actual ad

Answer (score 0):

One more think to note for those still struggling

```
  xmlns:ads="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"

 <ads:AdControl Height="80"
                           Width="480"
                           AdUnitId="Image480_80"
                           ApplicationId="test_client" />
```

As in example. Declaring ads and the namespace is super important.
In my project i just inserted the adcontrol part alt + enter for resharper to do the rest of the work which he didnt. He replaces ads with UI and there was no error compilation still the ads wouldn't show. When i declared ads myself and changed the adcontrol namespace. Everything worked fine.