# Cannot Integrate Microsoft Advertising sdk in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am not able to integrate the adcontrol in my windows phone 8 app.
In windows phone 8, the microsoft advertising sdk is already provided in the reference and hence have not downloaded the same.
Below is the code snippet I have used:

```
// Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ApplicationID = "test_client", AdUnitID = "Image480_80", 

        AdControl adControl = new AdControl("test_client",   // ApplicationID
                                            "Image480_80",   // AdUnitID
                                            true);           // isAutoRefreshEnabled
        // Make the AdControl size large enough that it can contain the image
        adControl.Width = 480;
        adControl.Height = 80;

        Grid grid = (Grid)this.LayoutRoot.Children[1];
        grid.Children.Add(adControl);            
    }
```

I have also added various capabilities as mentioned in this link:
[Windows phone ads not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746612/windows-phone-ads-not-working)

But still I am having no luck...At one place I read you need to have internet connection in order for adcontrol to be visible. Is it true?.

Anyways require help on the same.

Thanks In Advance!!!...

Comment: Anyone any help on the same...

Comment: I am facing similar issue, I tried both methods but ads from pub center are not working at all.

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

Issue that I have found in your question is of capabilities, Keep one thing in mind that there is a change in capabilities from windows phone-7 to windows phone-8.

Capabilities that you have added are according to windows phone-7(as you mentioned from link).

You can find required capabilities at: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-manifest-capabilities(v=msads.20).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-manifest-capabilities%28v=msads.20%29.aspx)

Sample:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AdControl adCntrl = new AdControl();
        adCntrl.Height = 80;
        adCntrl.Width = 480;
        adCntrl.ApplicationId = "test_client";
        adCntrl.AdUnitId = "Image480_80";
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(adCntrl);
    }
```

with Capabilities:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you did all the rest of the requirement stuff correctly and downloaded the Microsoft Ads SDK and added it in to the reference

Top of the main page

```
using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;
```

In MainPage class initialize these

```
Grid adGrid = new Grid();
StackPanel adStackPanel = new StackPanel();
AdControl adControl = new AdControl("test_client", "Image480_80", true);
```

In Constructor do this

```
adControl.Width = 480;
adControl.Height = 80;
adStackPanel.Children.Insert(0, adControl);
adGrid.Children.Insert(0, adStackPanel);
adGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
adGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
this.DrawingSurfaceBackground.Children.Insert(0, adGrid);


//Optional
adControl.ErrorOccurred += adControl_ErrorOccurred;
void adControl_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AdControl ad = (AdControl)sender;

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine(

           "error in ad control '" + ad.Name + "': " + e.Error.Message);

                    Debug.WriteLine("ad control '" + ad.Name + "' visibility = " + ad.Visibility);
                });

            }

            catch (Exception evnt)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("oh no! " + evnt.Message);
            }
        }
```