# Adcontrol Windows Phone does not show

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have read this (similar) question: [Windows phone ads not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746612/windows-phone-ads-not-working)
And I have read this [blog post](http://whiletruecode.tumblr.com/tagged/Windows-Phone). But it still does not work.
I have the feeling that it has something to do with my references. Or is it that it does not show up debugging the app on my phone? (because my cpu is too old to run emulation)

[image: references]

my xaml:

```
xmlns:ads="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
```

and below:

```
<ads:AdControl x:Name="showMeTheMoney" 
                  ApplicationId="a pubcenter id" 
                  AdUnitId="a pubcenter ad unit id" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Height="80" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                  Grid.Row="1" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="480"/>
```

in pubcenter I have registered the app and adunit and also the size (480 x 80)
But it is still a black square on my phone.
Also the manifest has the required rights:

[image: manifest rights]

[image: why you no show?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ads using real **ApplicationId** and **AdUnitId** are not working in emulator, for testing you should use test values located here:
[Test Values for AdUnitId and ApplicationId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-test-mode-values%28v=msads.20%29.aspx)

Comment: Not just emulator, also when you test on the phone like me, this pointed me in the right direction! Thanks!