# Microsoft advertising SDK for windows phone 8 (XAML)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to add an ad to my app.

This is my XAML

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,343,12,43" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <UI1:AdControl Name="AdUnit" AdUnitId="test_client" 
                       ApplicationId="Image480_80" 
                       Height="80"  
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

This is my code

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        AdUnit.ErrorOccurred += AdUnit_ErrorOccurred;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }
    void AdUnit_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ad error " + e.Error.Message.ToString());
    }
```

When I deploy this to the device `null reference` occurs in

```
     AdUnit.ErrorOccurred += AdUnit_ErrorOccurred;
```

I followed everything from MSDN. 
I'm using VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have all these `capabilities` in your WMAppManifest:

```
ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER
ID_CAP_MEDIA_LIB
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER
ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT
```

a sample xaml:

```
<my:AdControl Visibility="Visible" ErrorOccurred="OnAdError_ErrorOccurred" AdUnitId="10020750" ApplicationId="e1e3c23b-3a59-4119-852e-8ad0a7f78f11" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,6,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" />
```

.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;

namespace WP_AdApp
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private AdControl adControl;
    private const string APPLICATION_ID = "e1e3c23b-3a59-4119-852e-8ad0a7f78f11";
    private const string AD_UNIT_ID = "10020750";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    private void OnAdError_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("AdControl error: " + e.Error.Message);
    }
}
}
```

For more have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147650/adcontrol-windows-phone-does-not-show?rq=1)

Hope it helps!

Comment: the test values worked in the emulator 
but on the device dosent work