# Error adding capability in windows phone app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows phone app in Visual studio 2012 and finding difficulties showing pub center ads. I have searched that we need to add certain capabilities reference : [Windows phone ads not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746612/windows-phone-ads-not-working), I have added all the capabilities but while adding **"ID_CAP_MEDIA_LIB"** its throws an error

> "The Name attribute is Ivalid - The value "ID_CAP_MEDIA_LIB"is Invalid
>   according to its datatype 'string' - The enumeration constraint
>   failed."

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You add capability from wpmanifest interface or you edit?

Comment: Look my answer, this capability doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hum this capability doesn't not exit.

```
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" />
```

You need =>

```
ID_CAP_IDENTIFY_USER
ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER
ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler to the Error Event on the AdControl, by catching that or adding a break point and drilling into the error event args you can normally pinpoint what the specific problem is or which capability your app is lacking during development.

As MatDev8 alluded to, it's probably best just to add capabilities through the wpmanifest UI.