# AdMob ads not showing on Windows Phone 8 device

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8, admob, device, ads

I've got a problem with AdMob on Windows Phone 8. Ads are showing fine on emulator, but not on actual device (Nokia Lumia 520). 'FailedToReceiveAd' event is triggerd, error Code is: "NetworkError".

PS
I put correct AdUnitId. I've tried it in google example app - result is the same.

Any Ideas?

Best regards,

Tom

Comment: If you could provide some of your code? Just look into this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746612/windows-phone-ads-not-working?rq=1

Comment: As I said, the error is happening even with adMob example app. Here's link: 
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download?hl=pl#downloadwp

Is anyone who is using adMob sdk for Windows Phone 8 can share his opinion?

Comment: As I could see that the error is with your network...are you trying this in your device or emulator?

Comment: I'm running the app both on emulator and device (Nokia Lumia 520). Emulator works good, device - no ads and still getting 'NetworkError'. 

Kulasangar, do you use adMob for WP8?

Comment: Yep I've done using an AdMob sample from the exact place you did. Check the Ids' whether you've entered correctly..um unable to share the code with you at the moment.

Comment: The sample app (interstitial) worked out of the box for me on our Lumia 520 today. Just had to enter the ID. Might be a stupid question, but does your device have an active internet connection? I got this error when testing the ads with internet disabled ...

Comment: I'm having the same problem, both with my app and the sample. always NetworkError. Anyone know of any Resolutions?